# How to check offset is defined within MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, session

How would I overcome the `Notice: Undefined offset:` error in instances where the some of the $_SESSION['basket'] array keys do not exist?

**MYSQL**

```
                  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from product
                  WHERE product_id IN ('".$_SESSION['basket'][0]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][1]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][2]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][3]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][4]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][5]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][6]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][7]['itemid']."',
                  '".$_SESSION['basket'][8]['itemid']."')");
```

Can I use if (isset($_SESSION['basket'][0]['itemid']) within the mysql_query statement?

At the moment when the `['basket']` offsets do not exist the Notice error message is given.

Could anybody tell me the correct way to check the existence of these offsets before / or within the mysql_query statement?

Thanks

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API is deprecated.

Comment: A mysql Statement is a simple string... You could just do your checks before, and build up the string accordingly and run the query after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `$_SESSION['basket']` array and build the `IN` list dynamically.

```
$itemids = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item) {
    $itemids[] = "'" . $item['itemid'] . "'";
}

$itemids_str = implode(',', $itemids);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($itemids_str)"
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar - this has produced the correct result without the Notice warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
***NOTE:*** `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*`

```
  $in = '';

  foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $item){
       $in .= $item['itemid'] .',';
  }

  if(strlen($in) > 0)
     $in = substr($in, 0, strlen($in)-1);


  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from product
              WHERE product_id IN ('" . $in ."')");
```